# strange .NET process flag

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Was investigating in memory leaks in web app. And in Process Explorer (Sysinternals) found flag for process, HoardGC (screenshot attached).
Googling by HoardGC not give any result. Can someone explain what it means? Really interesting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, why this was not indexed by Google ? :)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2005/10/03/476750.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231027%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Care to include a summary here? - "link only" answers tend to be frowned upon - links *can* go dead (or be moved) and a summary can at least still be useful (and may help a future maintainer re-locate the page if the link is dead)

Comment: Fear not. Google has since indexed your post.